# Angular / TypeScript : Get Value in a table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I get value with angular / typescript in this table ..

[image: My console log]

How can I get the value of code and label ..
I tried to do this code but it's not worked :

MyComponent.ts

```
  jsonsTypes = []; // define here global variable
    saveFolder() {
        let tab = [];
         this.adminService.getLabelByCode(code).subscribe(
          labelByCode => {
            tab.push({
              'code': code,
              'label': labelByCode.label
            });
          });
           this.jsonTypes.push(tab);
          //here when I do console.log(tab); ==> I have the result of the picture
        for (var index = 0; index < this.jsonTypes.length; index++) {
            console.log(jsonTypes[index]); 
            console.log(jsonTypes[index].code); // ==> undefined            
            // How can I get value ?
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the for inside subscribe, because the value is assigned once getLabelByCode(code) finished. You are doing the for loop outside this and therefore, it loops through an empty array.

Comment: Your subscribe-method doesn't really fit in there. the subscription should be done once.

Comment: I do mistake in my first post -- I edit it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will result the code:

```
console.log(jsonTypes[index][0].code);
```

But the problem is, that you don't need to make "tab" to an array.

Try this... It's not tested, but should work.

```
jsonsTypes = []; // define here global variable
saveFolder() {
  this.adminService.getLabelByCode(code).subscribe(
    labelByCode => {
     this.jsonTypes.push({
        'code': code,
        'label': labelByCode.label
      });
    });

  for (var index = 0; index < this.jsonTypes.length; index++) {
    console.log(jsonTypes[index]); 
    console.log(jsonTypes[index].code);
  }
}
```